# In-place substitution for paste command

Tags: shell, text-processing, pipe, io-redirection

When I run the following code

```
echo '1' > file.txt
echo '2' | paste file.txt - > file.txt
```

I would expect the content of `file.txt` be `1   2`, because the `paste` command as it name suggests should put the two strings simply side-by-side.
However, it is just `2`.

Could anyone of you point me towards additional diagnostics to run in order to pin down the problem.

Comment: Why would you use paste?  Just `echo '2' >> file.txt`.  Your issue is that you are using `>` rather than `>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It was just a minimal example. Actually, I would like to paste multiline output to a multiline file.

Answer (score 3):

The redirection to `file.txt` at the end of your `paste` command is truncating your file before `paste` has a chance to read it.

Try

```
echo 2 | paste file.txt - > file2.txt
```

or if you have [`sponge`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) installed

```
echo 2 | paste file.txt - | sponge file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your answer. Both solutions work. Solution 1 has the disadvantage of creating an additional file (maybe that's unavoidable). Solution 2 reduces portability, because it needs additional software to be installed. Your answer is still helpful, though.